# UIScrollView going in infinite recursion

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I want to implement a `UIScrollView` in my controller because the height of the view is greater than the iphone screen size.

I have my view designed in the story board for which I have created an `IBOutlet` in .h file

In .m, I am doing the following for creating `UIScrollView`:

```
-(void) addScrollView
{
    UIScrollView* ScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    [self.ScrollView addSubview:self.myStoryBoardView];
    self.ScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    [self.view addSubview:self.ScrollView];   
}
```

In the last line of the above, it goes in infinite loop.
Kindly suggest

Comment: Use ScrollView NOT self.ScrollView

Comment: That does not solve problem. Actually I had ScrollView in .h file so I have written it with self. For posting it here I have initialized Scrollview in the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to make an UIScrollview (called ScrollView) yet you add self.ScrollView, which is probably a defined IBOutlet property (in your .h or .m file in the interface) made in Storyboard. Try this code and get rid of the UIScrollView in your Storyboard.
Also don't use ScrollView but instead use scrollView as apple documentation suggests.

```
-(void) addScrollView
{
    UIScrollView* scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    [scrollView addSubview:self.myStoryBoardView];
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];
}
```

Comment: This does not solve. My app crashes yet again. I have a view in the story board and I am trying to add scroll view to it programmatically since its height is more than iPhone height.

Comment: You do know self.view calls your main view and probably not the view you have build in Storyboards? Have you made an IBOutlet property of your custom view? If yes then what name did you give it? Because I doubt it is view. Please show us some more code if you want more help.

Comment: Ahh! I have created the IBOutlet property for the main view.

Comment: I am trying to add another view to this in Storyboard but the view is not being displayed

Comment: However if I turn autolayouts on for this subview, the subview is displayed but in the rightmost bottom of the screen

Comment: As far as I know turning autolayout on or off is done for the whole project, not just one element (like a subview). If you are working with Storyboard try setting constraints. If you have never worked with constraints try this excellent tutorial from Ray Wenderlich [link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2)

Answer (score 1):

Replace this line:

```
UIScrollView* ScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
```

With:

```
self.ScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
```

**Explanation:**
You are initializing a separate local `UIScrollView` in your `addScrollView` method. You local object declaration overrides class instance's object declaration. However following code lines:

```
[self.ScrollView addSubview:self.myStoryBoardView];
self.ScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
[self.view addSubview:self.ScrollView];
```

are called on your class  instance `UIScrollView`'s object, which is uninitialized. That's why when you add uninitialized object as subview on any object, your app gets crashed.

Comment: This does not solve. My app crashes yet again. I have a view in the story board and I am trying to add scroll view to it programmatically since its height is more than iPhone height.

Answer (score 0):

He is right. Either add scroll view in the storyboard or from the code. You are setting height of scroll view equal to the height of your self.view instead set height to self.myStoryBoardView.

```
 -(void) addScrollView
{
UIScrollView* scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
[scrollView addSubview:self.myStoryBoardView];
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, self.myStoryBoardView.frame.size.height);
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];
```

}

Comment: This does not solve. My app crashes yet again. I have a view in the story board and I am trying to add scroll view to it programmatically since its height is more than iPhone height.

Comment: Try to add the view to the scroll view programmatically. Or directly add scroll view in the storyboard and then add your view to that scroll view and then make IBOulet for the scroll view.